# Dictionary of named ranges in sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a large number of named ranges in it. I would like to be able to get data from them in an efficient manner. Preferably in a python dictionary with the name of the range as the key and the value as the value. Or someway to make a pseudo workbook that lets me read a sheet without all the calls to excel.

Right now I am getting the value from each named range individually. This works, but is very slow. Ideally there would be one or two calls to get all of the named ranges. I am currently using a @xw.sub to get the values.

```py
@xw.sub
def get_named_ranges():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    ranges = {}
    ranges['MyNamedRange1'] = wb.sheets['sheet1'].['MyNamedRange1'].value
    ranges['MyNamedRange2'] = wb.sheets['sheet1'].['MyNamedRange2'].value
    ranges['MyNamedRange3'] = wb.sheets['sheet1'].['MyNamedRange3'].value
```

[image: Named Range Example]

Comment: You can loop through the names collections (`for name in wb.names`:) and access properties like `name.refers_to_range.value` and `name.name`. Not sure if it's faster actually, but might still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this.

[image]

```py
from pandas import *
xls = ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
print(df.to_dict())
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what I am looking for. I have added a image to my question to clarify. My named ranges aren't in columns, but just somewhere on the sheet.